# Updating DNS server Resource Records with MicrosoftDNS classes (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, dns

I am writing an app for doing changes to DNS resource records on local server.

I wrote a function to do it:

```
    public void UpdateDomainRecord(string domainName, string recordname, IEnumerable<JProperty> content)
    {
        ResourceRecord Rezults = new ResourceRecord();
        string wql = "";
        wql += " SELECT * ";
        wql += " FROM MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord";
        wql += " WHERE OwnerName = '" + recordname + '.' + domainName + "'";

        ObjectQuery q = new ObjectQuery(wql);

        ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(this.Session, q);
        ManagementObjectCollection col = s.Get();
        int total = col.Count;

        foreach (ManagementObject o in col)
        {
            foreach (JProperty prop in content)
            {
                o.SetPropertyValue(prop.Name.ToString(),prop.Value.ToString());
            }

            o.Put();

        }
    }
```

It seems **o.Put()** method does not work: the loop changed the property of ManagementObject object but changes is not saved on server.

1. The app has all access it needs to connect to server.
2. I'm not trying to change properties that can not be changed.

Do you have any ideas on why it is not working?

Comment: Is the SetPropertyValue moving the pointer to next value in the resource?  Then Put is not necessary which does the same.

Comment: But still... It does not save anything to server.

Comment: You do need the put.  You may be hitting a timeout so use following :  o.Put(PutOptions.InfiniteTimeout)